# How to make multiple divs take up all avaible space without hardcoding their size?

Tags: html, css, parent-child

I have parent div with specified size width: 40rem and height: 24rem.
Inside I have multiple child elements, 5 divs at this moment.
I want them to take all available space  even when amount of child elements will change.

Now I've just specified that each child's height will be 1/5  of parent element and they fit nicely. But I want it to be responsive  so even when there will be only 4 or 6 child elements they will cover parent div fully as well. Ideally I want to do it in pure CSS without JS or any additional frameworks.
This is my HTML code with Tailwind classes:
`

```
            <div class="mx-auto w-[80%] md:w-full h-72 sm:h-64 md:h-96">
                    <div style="background-image: url('/images/camp1.png'); background-size: 100%"
                        class="w-full h-1/5 bg-right bg-no-repeat">
                        sadhsahd

                    </div>
                    <div style="background-image: url('/images/camp2.png'); background-size: 100%"
                        class="w-full h-1/5 bg-center bg-no-repeat">
                        sadhsahd

                    </div>
                    <div style="background-image: url('/images/camp3.png'); background-size: 100%;"
                        class="w-full h-1/5 flex relative bg-center bg-no-repeat">
                        safas

                    </div>
                    <div style="background-image: url('/images/camp4.png');"
                        class="w-full h-1/5 bg-center bg-no-repeat">
                        sadhsahd

                    </div>
                    <div style="background-image: url('/images/camp5.png');" 
                       class="w-full h-1/5 bg-left bg-no-repeat">
                        sadhsahd
                    </div>
             </div>
```

`
[image: output view]

Comment: Try `flex-grow`: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the blocks to be equal to the entire height of the parent block. To do this, you can set a height of 100% for them, and set a property for the parent block FLEX

```css
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 24rem;
}
.wrap__block {
    background-image: url("https://www.koolinar.ru/all_image/recipes/151/151801/recipe_3cb3bdff-9436-4ac2-9ced-ee669eef0d2c.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="wrap__block"></div>
    <div class="wrap__block"></div>
    <div class="wrap__block"></div>
</div>
```